# Modify TYPO3 Frontend TypoScript from extension, using core hook

Tags: php, hook, typo3, frontend, typoscript

I've tryied a lot of things, and hooks for modifying the TypoScript configuration from and handmade extension. 
Here's the hooks I tested :

- `tslib_fe::initFEuser()`
- `tslib_fe::checkDataSubmission()`
- `tslib_fe::configArrayPostProc()`
- `t3lib_pagerenderer::renderPreProcess()`
- `t3lib_pagerenderer::renderPostProcess()`

I try to modify the TypoScript configuration by `$ref->tmpl->setup` and `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup` inside pagerenderer and tslib_fe hooks.

I've looking for other usefull hooks but not found.
If someone have an idea, a clue or any helping information, drop me a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With hook "includeStaticTypoScriptSourcesAtEnd" you can include any TS at the end of Typoscript stack so you can effectivly overwrite any setting.

Example of how to use this hook is in extension "templavoila_framework".